# How to set the edit text when keyboard is up?

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity where I have goole map with fragment, and in the bottom I have an editbox. So as I am clicking on the edit box, then soft keyboard is showing. But ti is hiding my editbox. So how can I get my editbox top of soft keyboard. Pleas help me. Here is my code.:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/grey_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="524dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/backLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBack"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/back" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLocationName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Kommentare"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/deleteLikeLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTrash"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/trash"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/like"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLiked"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/like_button_focus"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Body Part -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bodyLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgPostLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgPost"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mapFragmentLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgMap"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <!--
                 <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

                -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listRelatedCommentLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="5.7"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/frag_list"
                android:name="com.handmark.pulltorefresh.extras.listfragment.PullToRefreshListFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <!--
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listRelatedComment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>

            -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- footer -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footerLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtRelatedComments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/bottom_search"
                    android:hint="Kommentieren…"
                    android:maxLength="140"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sendButtonLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAbsenden"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Absenden"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my manifest I tried

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why not use `adjustResize `

Comment: I tried it also it is shrinking my whole layout with edit box, it is not giving proper solution.

Comment: you can put your layout into a scrollview.

Comment: I also tried it but, since scrollview keep height matchparent, so below LinearLayout keep height wrapcontent. So my whole layout becomes mashed. You think I need to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

on the Activity. Here is a snippet from my code.

```
  <activity
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:name=".youractivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: Please check by adding adjustResize. See my edited post. It should work now.

Comment: You can also do
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

dynamically in you activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <activity
            android:name="youractivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

use this code in your manifest file where you declare your activity in manifest in which you want your output hope i will work for you